# IOS | What is this codec - 'lghrn'?

Tags: ios, video, codec

Was wondering if anyone would like to explain what this codec actually is - `lghrn` .

So what I'm doing is I've connected my iPhone 11 (IOS 14.4.2) to Xcode to see it's logs, after that I've opened up YouTube, and I was looking for the currently playing video's codec in the logs, when I discovered this `lghrn`

[Logs from Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6lbS.png)

Searching it on Google lead me to no result, except for this tweet:

https://twitter.com/PoomSmart/status/1292033535084134400

From this tweet does it mean that `lghrn` is actually a `vp9` codec?